# How to make phenyl benzene (Biphenyl)?

Tags: chemfig

```
\chemname{\chemfig{*6(-=-(-{Cl})=-=)}}{Chlorobenzene} 
+ 2 Na + \chemfig{*6(-=-=-(-{Cl})=)} $\xrightarrow{Ether}$
```

It is fitig reaction. The major product is biphenyl. I couldnt code that..

Comment: Welcome, we have mathemaicians, physicists, lawyers, linguists and more in the helping squad. The number of chemists is low. A fast answer will depend on a good question, i.e. a bit more detail. For example, i don't know from the top of my hat what bophenyl looks like.

Answer (score 2):

It's just the same as your chlorobenzene only with another ring instead of the chlorine:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}

\chemfig{*6(=-=(-*6(=-=-=-))-=-)}

\end{document}
```